# No funcionan los shortcodes en elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

Estoy intentando crear un shortcode que muestre el precio de oferta o el normal en casi de que este, pero me da error fatal

```
function price_get() {

    global $product ;

    $precio_normal = $product->get_regular_price();
    $precio_oferta = $product->get_sale_price();

    if ( $precio_oferta > 0 ) echo  $precio_oferta;
    if ( $precio_oferta < 0 ) echo  $precio_normal;

    echo $precio_normal;
}

add_shortcode('price', 'price_get');
```

[image: En el panel de elementor me sale]

pero, cuando le doy actualizar, me sale este error fatal [image: Este es el error]

Comment: Diria que más bien no funciona `$product->get_regular_price()` porque te devuelve un `Call to member function ... on bool` que segun veo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813722/what-means-call-to-a-member-function-on-boolean-and-how-to-fix) podria ser porque es una propiedad que no existe en ese controlador.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con algo como esto

```
function jbs_get_product_price(){

    global $woocommerce;

    // Obtenemos el producto
    // si estas en un loop esto es igual a usar la global $product
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    // get_the_ID() llama al id del producto actual, pero puedes obtenerlo de otro forma o de forma manual

    // Obtenemos los precios
    $precio_regular = $product->get_regular_price();
    $precio_oferta = $product->get_sale_price();

    // Verificamos si existe el precio de oferta
    if ( $precio_oferta ) {
        $html = $precio_oferta;
    } else {
        $html = $precio_regular;
    }

    // Retornamos un valor
    // Usar return es importante para evitar problemas al usar los shortcodes con los editores
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'jbs_price', 'jbs_get_product_price' );
```

Comment: Line 354
Message Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_regular_price() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\gomobile\wp-content\themes\machic-child\functions.php:354 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gomobile\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(356): jbs_get_product_price('', '', 'jbs_price') #1 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\gomobile\wp-includes\shortcodes.php(228): preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(jbs_pr...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[jbs_price]') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\gomobile\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\widgets\ me devuelve ese error bro

Comment: Personalmente no me ha pasado pero intenta declarar antes de todo global $woocommerce;